# Add a custom view at the top of views in activity Programatically

Tags: android, android-activity, view

I want to add a custom view (that contains a layout with button and text view) to every Activity I need my custom view name is NetworkErrorView and I have another class that help me observe network status change!

I want to show my custom view on top of other view in every activity that I bulid my NetworkErrorView like this

```
private NetworkErrorView networkErrorView=new NetworkErrorView(this).build();
```

And when network stats is change I want to change visibility from Gone to Visible(onChange is called when my network status changed):

```
 @Override
public void onChange(boolean isConnected) {
    networkErrorView.networkErorrDialog(isConnected);
}
```

My `onChange()` (method work correctly but i cant see my custom view when I change visibility! Can anyone help me??

**NetworkErrorView**:

```
public class NetworkErrorView  {

private ViewGroup mRootView;
private Activity mActivity;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private View view;
private Animation translationIn;
private Button btnNetwork;
private LinearLayout networkContainer;
private boolean networkStatus;

public NetworkErrorView(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    this.mRootView = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    this.mActivity = activity;
    this.mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
}

public NetworkErrorView build(){
    view= Assist.inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_network_error,mRootView,false);
    //View.inflate(mActivity, R.layout.dialog_network_error, mRootView);
    btnNetwork=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_error_network);
    btnNetwork.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    networkContainer=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_error_networkcontainer);
    translationIn= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity,R.anim.anim_wifi_container_in);
    mRootView.addView(view, 1);
    return this;
}



public void networkErorrDialog(boolean isConnected){
    networkStatus=isConnected;
    if(isConnected){
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
       view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.bringToFront();
        translationIn= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity, R.anim.anim_wifi_container_in);
        networkContainer.setAnimation(translationIn);
    }
}


View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!networkStatus){
            mActivity.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

        }
    }
};
```

}

**mActivity**:

```
public class mActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkObserver {

private NetworkErrorView networkErrorView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    FontManager.instance().setTypeface(getWindow().getDecorView());
    addView();
    NetworkManager.init(this);
//...
}

private void addView(){
   //...
    networkErrorView=new NetworkErrorView(this).build();
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean isConnected) {
    networkErrorView.networkErorrDialog(isConnected);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the view is being added, but because you are adding the view in the 1th position it is not being shown so try something like this

```
public NetworkErrorView build(){
    view= Assist.inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_network_error,mRootView,false);
    //View.inflate(mActivity, R.layout.dialog_network_error, mRootView);
    btnNetwork=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_error_network);
    btnNetwork.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    networkContainer=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_error_networkcontainer);
    translationIn= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mActivity,R.anim.anim_wifi_container_in);
    mRootView.addView(view, 0); //Change this form 1 to 0
    return this;
}
```

Comment: i tried 0,1,getChiledCount() and getChiledCount()-1 but not work

Comment: inside you onChange method log the result of `((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildCount()`

Comment: result of getChildCount() is 2